# SetTimeout for mousein and mouseout, doesn't wait when mousleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, mouseleave

```js
var time = 2000;
var t;
var th;
var hover = function($element) {
  clearTimeout(th);
  $element.parents('.tbody').find('.hotel').removeClass('hover active');
  $element.find('.hotel').addClass('hover');
}
var hoverOut = function($element) {
  clearTimeout(th);
  $element.find('.hotel').removeClass('hover');
}
var enable = function($element) {
  $element.parents('.tbody').find('.hotel').removeClass('active');
  $element.find('.hotel').removeClass('hover').addClass('active');
}
$(function() {
  $('.price').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    th = setTimeout(function() {
      hover($this);
    }, time);
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(th);
    th = setTimeout(hoverOut($this), time)
  });
  $('.price').on('click', function() {
    enable($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
.price {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.hotel {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}
.hotel.hover {
  display: block;
}
.hotel.active {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">
  <span>Hover Me</span>
  <div class="hotel">I am a hotel</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, It waits the time when you mouseenter, but when mousleave the function is executed right away,

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function instead of passing the function reference. You can use the `setTimeout` callback function to call the function with parameter.

When you use `hoverOut($this)` as callback function of `setTimeout` the function `hoverOut` is called immediately.

```
// See this section
th = setTimeout(function () {
    hoverOut($this)
}, time)
```

**Demo**

```js
var time = 2000;
var t;
var th;
var hover = function($element) {
  clearTimeout(th);
  $element.parents('.tbody').find('.hotel').removeClass('hover active');
  $element.find('.hotel').addClass('hover');
}
var hoverOut = function($element) {
  clearTimeout(th);
  $element.find('.hotel').removeClass('hover');
}
var enable = function($element) {
  $element.parents('.tbody').find('.hotel').removeClass('active');
  $element.find('.hotel').removeClass('hover').addClass('active');
}
$(function() {
  $('.price').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    th = setTimeout(function() {
      hover($this);
    }, time);
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(th);
    th = setTimeout(function() {
      hoverOut($this)
    }, time)
  });
  $('.price').on('click', function() {
    enable($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
.price {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.hotel {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.hotel.hover {
  display: block;
}
.hotel.active {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">
  <span>Hover Me</span>
  <div class="hotel">I am a hotel</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But please check my edit, adding another .price item, then it works only for the first time, any idea why?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I think your edit has changed this into somewhat of a different question.  There's now a timing issue, which isn't anything to do with the original problem - it ought to be a separate question.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I checked your snippet, it's working fine for both the elements

Comment: @Tushar If you move from the first to the second quickly there does appear to be an issue.  Slowly slowly and it's fine - but as I mentioned, it's not the same question at all.

Comment: It's not working for me, just one element and the first time only. On Mac and Firefox.. ?

Comment: Ok, so just you know, as there where adjacent elements (no margin), I needed to clear the timout before the mouseenter function aswell, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

On mouse over, you're running this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        hover($this);
    }, time);
})
```

On leave, you're running this:

```
th = setTimeout(hoverOut($this), time)
```

Note that `hoverOut` isn't wrapped in a `function` in the same way as `hover` - so it's running immediately, and the result of the function is being passed to `setTimeout` rather than the `hoverOut` function reference itself.